# acts_as_taggable: Create tags depending on context that could be chosen by a user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, acts-as-taggable-on

I would like to know if the acts_as_taggable gem could suit my situation.

What I want to achieve is an admin could add a list of tags with a specific context and user can pick some of them depending on the context.

For example, Admin can create the following tags:

#### Tags group 1

- Context: behaviour_skills
- Names: analytics, curious, ...

#### Tags group 2

- Context: it_skills
- Names: ruby, python, ...

and User 1 would select (for exemple):

- in the context of behaviour (specific input): analytic, ...
- in the context of it skills (specific input): ruby, c#, ...

My question is, regarding the acts_as_taggable tables, the table Tag only contains the name. The context is tied on taggings only.

In that way, do I add a "context" field in Tag ?

and creating my tags like so:

```
list = [{name: 'tag 1', context: 'context 1'}, {name: 'tag 2', context: 'context 2' }, ...]
list.each do |tag|
  ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag.new(name: tag[:name], context: tag[:context]).save
end
```

and displaying them like this:

```
skill_tags = ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag.where(context: skills)
```

or the API has specific method that could fit my case ? or doing it from scratch ?

(Basically, the system I want to achieve is very similar to the "favorite tags", "ignored tags" on SO)

Thanks for your suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

It most definitely could be used in your situation.

Perhaps your use case dictates that you save "context" on the tag, but I don't know why you would.  It seems you would be better suited to have a key in the user class and better yet a YAML file as a key.  For example you yaml file could look like this:

```
Behavior:
  - Analytics
  - Curious
IT:
  - Ruby
  - Python
```

Then make your YAML file a constant on the user

```
TRAITS_KEY = YAML.load_file({path_to_yaml_file})
```

Then you can call it where ever needed

```
User::TRAITS_KEY['Behavior'] <= would return ['Analytics', 'Curious']
```

Then when creating your select boxes only give the options to tag based on the context.  You could make the key your your context and then options are only ones in the array from that context.  It is implied that when tagging something with "Ruby" it is an IT skill based on your YAML file.  Then when searching again you can use the YAML file (taken from the acts_as_taggable docs edited for this example)

```
# Find users that matches all given tags ('Super Coders'):
User.tagged_with(User::TRAITS_KEY['IT'], :match_all => true)

# Find users with any of the specified tags ('Any one with dev skills'):
User.tagged_with(User::TRAITS_KEY['IT'], :any => true)

# Find users that has not been tagged with it tags ('Non Devs'):
User.tagged_with(User::TRAITS_KEY['IT'], :exclude => true)
```

Their docs are super helpful.  But I don't know that saving context on tags is needed.  As a warning I did not test any of my above code it was all done from memory and/or looking at my existing projects where I had similar needs.  This should at least give you the concept of how I might approach this.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You could create a migration for a tag settings model, whereby you reference the tag, and create a target_type.

```
create_table :tag_settings do |t|
  t.references :tag, null: false, foreign_key: true
  t.string :target_type
end
```

Then you can create scopes on the target type, in order to get the relevant list of Tags, to be used anywhere.